# PHP Ignoring Digits to the Right of the Decimal Point in Equation

Tags: php, floating-point

I have a variable `$x` whose value is read in from an XML file.  The value being read from the XML is 1.963788, nothing more, nothing less.  When I output `$x`, I see that the value in `$x` is in fact 1.963788.  All is right with the world.

But then when I use x in an equation such as

```
$pl = $x*125.0-200.0;
```

The value of `$pl` ends up being -75.  For whatever reason, PHP seems to be ignoring, or just getting rid of, the digits to the right of the decimal point in `$x`, which makes `$x` contain 1.  I thought maybe there was a snowball's chance in hell that this occurred in other languages too, so I wrote it up in C++ and, big surprise, I get the right answer of 45.4735.

Anyone ever encountered this before or know what's going on?  Thanks.

Comment: This should work in PHP w/o problems too. Ensure that `$x` really contains a float. What does `var_dump($x)` give when inserted right before the line `$pl = ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [floatval](http://php.net/manual/de/function.floatval.php)?
Maybe PHP interprets your number as a string and the standard conversion just casts it to integer.

Comment: Nope, PHP would transparently cast a `string` of `'1.963788'` to a proper `float`. It would convert to `int` if it sees a character not valid for a numeric format, e.g. `'1,963788'` would result in `(int) 1`

Comment: Actually, it would seem that Daniel was right.  Sorry about this; I am used to the way Perl would handle this :)  In PHP, apparently if it's read in from XML it's a string unless the programmer explicitly specifies otherwise.  Thanks!

Comment: Still nope. If so, the official PHP documentation of [String conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) would've been unnoticeably wrong for some years now^^. Anyway, got no time for further nitpicking^^

Answer (score 1):

It probably is due to the fact that `$x` is being interpreted as a string, and converted to an integer and not a float value.

Try:

```
$pl = (float) $x * 125.0 - 200.0;
```

Comment: PHP would handle this automatically, the string will be casted to float and result would be float: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 1):

Your number appears to have failed casting as a float.  If I use '1,963788' I get your result.  If I use '2,963788' I receive a result of 50.  According to the PHP docs for [intval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) (and that's what it appears PHP is trying to cast this as, an integer): 
`Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string. The common rules of integer casting apply.`

Check the value $x actually has carefully.  It may not be what you expect since PHP seems to disagree that it is, in fact, a float or it would have typed it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Just before you compute `$pl`, do a `var_dump` on `$x` to see what is the actual value stored in it. I've tried your code and it is returning the correct value 45.4735, so I might not be PHP's fault.